# How to find by id in set?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have entity Account which have a set of Company

```
class Account {
//other fields
 Set<Company> companies;
}
```

And my Company entity looks like

```
class Company {
 UUID id;
}
```

How can i correctly write a JPAmethod in AccountReposotiry for finding all account where one of company equals param?

Something like

findAllByCompaniesContainingId(UUID companyId);

Comment: `findAllByCompanies_Id(UUID companyId);`

Comment: with this method's name spring proposes param findAllByCompanies_Id(Company companies_id);

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below method in your `AccountReposotiry` to get all Companies by `companyId`

```
findAllByCompaniesId(UUID companyId);
```